# Can a parameterized trait specify that one of its abstract classes return a value of the same type as implementing classes?

Tags: scala

Say I have a trait like this:

```
trait BaseTrait[A] {
    def someMethod[B](f: A => T[B]): T[B]
}
```

I want `T` to basically be "the same type as the class that implements this method". In other words, I want to be able to write this:

```
class ConcreteClass[A] extends BaseTrait[A] {
    def someMethod[B](f: A => ConcreteClass[B]): ConcreteClass[B]
}
```

And have that method satisfy the trait's requirement for `someMethod`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

What you are asking about is called F-bound types, and this is the best explanation I've seen on the topic:
https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

The punch line is that you'll either want to switch to using typeclasses rather than inheritance, or you'll have to settle for getting almost all the way to what you want, like this:

```
trait BaseTrait[A <: BaseTrait[A]] { this: A => 
  def someMethod[B](f: A => T[B]): T[B]
}

class Concrete extends BaseTrait[Concrete]{  
  def someMethod[B](f: A => T[B]): T[B]
}
```

Now in your case your trait itself takes a type parameter, so you'll also have to work in an other type parameter, and use higher-kinded types like so:

```
trait BaseTrait[A, T[X] <: BaseTrait[X, T]] { this: T[A] =>
  def someMethod[B](f: A => T[B]): T[B]
}

class Concrete[A] extends BaseTrait[A, Concrete]{
  def someMethod[B](f: A => Concrete[B]): Concrete[B] = ???
}
//class DoesNotCompile[A] extends BaseTrait[Concrete, A]{
//  def someMethod[B](f: A => Concrete[B]): Concrete[B] = ???
//}

//class DoesNotCompile2[A] extends BaseTrait[DoesNotCompile2, A]{
//  def someMethod[B](f: A => Concrete[B]): Concrete[B] = ???
//}

object Ex {
  val concrete: Concrete[List[Int]] = new Concrete[List[Int]]
  val concrete2: Concrete[String] = concrete.someMethod(_ => new Concrete[String])

}
```

Comment: ```BaseTrait[T[X] <: BaseTrait[T[X], A], A]``` needs to be ```BaseTrait[T[X] <: BaseTrait[T, X], A]``` and the self type annotation is not needed. It's my favorite answer. it shows clearly that scala has first class support for the goal of the PO.

Comment: Actually the self-type is required, otherwise this can compile:

    class Oops[A] extends BaseTrait[A, Concrete] {
      def someMethod[B](f: A => Concrete[B]): Concrete[B] = ???
    }

Comment: It doesn't compile on my machine for many reasons. IDE is flashing red all over it.

Comment: Ignore the IDE and only trust scalac.

Comment: still doesn't compile. it's not for syntactic issues. have you tried in on yours?

Comment: same version. how can this possibly compile: ```Oops[A] extends BaseTrait[A, Concrete]```? you are omitting the type parameter for Concrete which is wrong cuz trait BaseTrait is not expeting a higher-kinded type on that position. also A Must be a higher kind which isn't

Comment: Oh, sorry when I edited my post a few minutes back, I switched the type parameters (I was trying to figure out why it wasn't compiling for me). If you copy paste the new code in, it should work

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like?:

```
trait BaseTrait[M[_], A] { self: M[A] =>
  def someMethod[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}

class ConcreteClass[A] extends BaseTrait[ConcreteClass, A] {
  def someMethod[B](f: A => ConcreteClass[B]): ConcreteClass[B] = ???
}
```

I think it would be difficult to get it more concrete than that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using a type member instead of a type parameter. I think it's down to personal preference which you prefer.

```
trait BaseTrait[A] {
  type Self[X] <: Base[X]
  def doSomething[B](f: A => Self[B]): Self[B]
}

class ConcreteClass[A] extends BaseTrait[A] {
  type Self[X] = ConcreteClass[X]
  def doSomething[B](f: A => ConcreteClass[B]): ConcreteClass[B] = ???
}
```

It wouldn't stop some concrete implementation from defining `Self` to be something other than itself, but I don't know of any solution to that (it's a common problem).

Comment: I think Martin Odersky said the same thing